# Sum List of IQueryable

Tags: linq-to-sql

Given a list IQueryables, how can you sum the count of each, without having multiple statements executed in the database?

```
 return queries
               .Sum(qy=> qy.Count());
```

The above works, but hits the database for each query.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @AdrianIftode: no, and with just 11 views (probably half from me), I don't have much hope for stackoverflow to help.

Comment: the bounty should fix this :)

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve? Something like select (select count(*) from q1), (select count(*) from q2)

Comment: @AdrianIftode, either that (except with a + instead of a comma) or a `union all` as a subquery and a Sum for the outer query.

Comment: Adrian's solution is working as such. I've tried some other options and I am sure I could find an alternative, but I can't guarantee it would be better. My idea was to get all queries, get the command object with db.GetCommand(query) and then combine the commands with some hand crafted SQL that I would then send via db.ExecuteQuery. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex: I ran across this problem as an interview question, with the restriction that only one line could be changed.  For this question it would have had to be the second line.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Check my answer below: instead of `.Sum(q=>q.Count())` you use `.CountAll()`.

Comment: Yes, but you wrote an entirely seperate function in order to do so.  I like your answer (and upvoted it) and it does work for my question.  I just feel that there is a one-liner that does it and I'm missing it, giving me an itch I can't scratch.  I thought I had it for a bit using `Aggregate((a, q) => a.Concat(q)).Count()` but that seems to hit the db for each concat.

Comment: @jmoreno - are you sure about that? `Aducci` posted the same as an answer. I tested that in EF and there is only one DB call. I take it though that Linq-to-Sql is probably no different?

Comment: @Igor: No, I had made a mistake in my testing, after seeing Aducci's answer, I retested and it worked as desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first use the `Aggregate` function with `Concat` to combine the IQueryable's and then `Count` the total like this:

```
 return queries.Aggregate((x,y) => x.Concat(y)).Count()
```

Comment: Wouldn't you still need to add the `.Sum()` somewhere?. Also does this execute a single DB hit or one for each IQueryable?

Comment: @Igor - No, since you are combining all the queries into one using `Concat` (which translates to `UNION ALL`), you just need to count the records of the combined query

Comment: It will only execute once, because `Aggregate` only returns a single `IQueryable`, and the query is only sent to the database once you call `Count()`

Comment: Nice job on the simple answer (*I upvoted*). I read a previous comment from the OP that he/she had tested this already but made a trip to the DB for each IQueryable so I read that as a truth without questioning it. I tested using EF and it works as you explained (which makes perfect sense). I imagine it works the same way with Linq-to-Sql.

Comment: Not to be a sour loser, but this doesn't work for "given a list IQueryables" if the underlying types of the IQueryable are different.(NotSupportedException: "Types in Union or Concat have different members assigned."). The working solution, in a one liner, is `queries.Select(q=>q.Select(z=>1)).Aggregate((x, y) => x.Concat(y)).Count();` which is exactly Adrian's solution. Since this answer doesn't work for the text of the question, which didn't specify a "one liner", I don't think it is the best.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from this idea `Sum(q1,q2) = q1.Concat(q2).Count()` I've tested the following extensions:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<object> ConcatAny<T,R>(this IQueryable<T> q1, IQueryable<R> q2)
    {
        return q1.Select(c=>(object)null).Concat(q2.Select(c=>(object)null));
    }

    public static IQueryable<object> ConcatAll(this IEnumerable<IQueryable<object>> queries)
    {
        var resultQuery = queries.First();
        foreach (var query in queries.Skip(1))
        {
            resultQuery = resultQuery.ConcatAny(query);
        }
        return resultQuery;
    }
}
```

I assumed you have heterogeneous queries like `IQueryable<T>`, `IQueryable<R>` so on and you are interested in counting all rows no matter which the source is.

So you might use these extensions like

```
var q1 = Table1.AsQueryable();
var q2 = Table2.AsQueryable();
var q3 = Table3.AsQueryable();

var queries = new IQueryable<object>[] {q1,q2,q3}; // we use here the covariance feature

return queries.ConcatAll().Count();
```

The generated SQL might look like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM (
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM (
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [Table1] AS [t0]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [Table2] AS [t1]
        ) AS [t2]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Table3] AS [t3]
    ) AS [t4]
```

I don't think is very effective though

Answer (score 2):

Ok, a few minutes late, but I got it!
Here is the code:

```
    public static class LinqExtensions
    {
        public static int CountAll(this IEnumerable<IQueryable<object>> queries)
        {
            if (queries == null || !queries.Any())
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Queries parameter cannot be null or empty");
            }
            Expression ex = Expression.Constant(0);
            foreach (var qy in queries)
            {
                // create count expression
                var expression = Expression.Call(
                  typeof(Queryable),
                  "Count",
                  new[] { qy.ElementType },
                  qy.Expression
                  );
                ex = Expression.Add(ex, expression);
            }
            return queries.First().Provider.Execute<int>(ex);
        }
    }
```

You use it as `queries.CountAll()` where queries is an `IEnumerable<IQueryable<object>>` as in Adrian's answer or even simple `IEnumerable<IQueryable>`.

Here is a sample SQL result from the profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT @p0 + ((
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [A] AS [t0]
    WHERE [t0].[i1] >= @p1
    )) + ((
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [B] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[i2] >= @p2
    )) + ((
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [C] AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[i3] >= @p3
    )) AS [value]',N'@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 int',@p0=0,@p1=2,@p2=2,@p3=2
```

Which is the representation of

```
    var a = db.GetTable<A>();
    var b = db.GetTable<B>();
    var c = db.GetTable<C>();

    var q1 = a.Where(v => v.i1 >= 2);
    var q2 = b.Where(v => v.i2 >= 2);
    var q3 = c.Where(v => v.i3 >= 2);

    var queries = new IQueryable<object>[] {
        q1,q2,q3
    };
```

Note that A, B and C are different objects/tables with different numbers of properties/columns and that the expressions are random Where filters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Entity Framework you can use an extension called [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended). There is a built in extension called `Future Queries`. This will allow you to specify that a query should be executed the next time a trip to the database is made.

NuGet command:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework.Extended
```

Sample code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var modelSet1 = context.Models.Where(x => x.ModelId < 25).FutureCount();
        var modelSet2 = context.Models.Where(x => x.ModelId > 25 && x.ModelId < 32).FutureCount();
        var modelSet3 = context.Models.Where(x => x.ModelId > 32).FutureCount();

        var queries = new [] {modelSet1, modelSet2, modelSet3};

        var countQueries = queries.Sum(x => x.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(countQueries);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Haven't been able to verify this works yet, but it sounds like exactly what I was hoping to do.  I think/thought it was possible with pin the bounds of the regular linq methods, but this is definitely viable.  Thanks.

Comment: @jmoreno - Glad to hear. Let me know if you have any other questions on it.

Comment: I can say that this doesn't work with Linq2SQL, although it does seem to be the correct solution: a Count that returns IQueryable

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex - correct. I had put that disclaimer at the top of my answer that this would only work with Entity Framework.